# Power BI REST API BadRequest for measures

Tags: powerbi

I have created a dataset without major incidence

```
{\"tableName\": \"Sales\"
,\"columns\": [ 
    {\"name\":\"ProductID\", \"dataType\":\"int64\", \"summarizeBy\":\"none\", \"isHidden\":\"True\", \"formatString\":\"#,##0\"}
    , {\"name\":\"Date\", \"dataType\":\"DateTime\", \"formatString\":\"dd/mm/yyyy\"}
    , {\"name\":\"TipID\", \"dataType\":\"int64\", \"summarizeBy\":\"none\", \"isHidden\":\"True\", \"formatString\":\"#,##0\"}
    , {\"name\":\"Sales\", \"dataType\":\"double\", \"formatString\":\"#,##0\"}
    ]
}
```

, but when I try to put some measure, always get a "BadRequest".

```
{\"tableName\": \"Sales\"
,\"columns\": [ 
    {\"name\":\"ProductID\", \"dataType\":\"int64\", \"summarizeBy\":\"none\", \"isHidden\":\"True\", \"formatString\":\"#,##0\"}
    , {\"name\":\"Date\", \"dataType\":\"DateTime\", \"formatString\":\"dd/mm/yyyy\"}
    , {\"name\":\"TipID\", \"dataType\":\"int64\", \"summarizeBy\":\"none\", \"isHidden\":\"True\", \"formatString\":\"#,##0\"}
    , {\"name\":\"Sales\", \"dataType\":\"double\", \"formatString\":\"#,##0\"}
    ]
    , \"measures\": [
        {\"name\": \"TrySales\", \"expression\": \"SUM(Sales[Sales])\"}
        ]
    }
```

I have created a "[Push Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_puttable#measure)" where only add measures, with the same error.

```
        HttpContent body = new StringContent(postBody);
        body.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsync(restUri, body).Result;
```

`JSON`

```
{\"tableName\": \"Sales\"
, \"measures\": [
    {\"name\": \"TrySales\", \"expression\": \"CALCULATE(SUM(Ventas[Venta]);SUM(Sales[Sales])\"}
  ]
}
```

I only found an example code [in this link](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/newdatasets/)..

The result from the `PUT`

**Headers**

```
 {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
  X-Frame-Options: deny
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  RequestId: 6aa4198c-8315-4517-8f78-b5f90e6d1375
  Access-Control-Expose-Headers: RequestId
  request-redirected: true
  home-cluster-uri: https://wabi-europe-north-b-redirect.analysis.windows.net/
  Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache
  Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2019 13:08:36 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}
```

**Request message**

```
 {Method: PUT, RequestUri: 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/1cd4f3cf-xxxx-41dd-83e4-c17708511d79/datasets/35b36723-ed24-xxxx-8e54-fc8e3a1503fe/tables/Sales'
, Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Accept: application/json
  Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkJCOE...
  Content-Type: application/json
  Content-Length: 147
}}
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
Response

```
Id = 37, Status = RanToCompletion
, Method = "{null}"
, Result = "{\"error\":{
    \"code\":\"BadRequest\"
    ,\"message\":\"Bad Request\"
    ,\"details\":[
        {\"message\":\"The property 'tableName' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.PowerBI.ServiceContracts.Api.Table'
        . Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.\"
        ,\"target\":\"tableSchema\"}
        ]
    }
    }
```

It seems a spelling error due to an error in the documentation. In [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_puttable) it appears as "tableName" and I have not found any more examples.

Comment: What is in the response content when you get a bad request?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov, I have completed the question with the PUT response content

Comment: The response content however is not here. As you can see in response headers, there is some content: `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`. The reason for the error is most likely there.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov, is a spelling error, at the end of the question I have put the detail. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It is an error in the documentation.
This [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_puttable#examples) in the documentation has `tableName` in the json. However, when you click on [Try it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_puttable#code-try-0) the body has `name`.

Using `name` instead of `tableName` worked for me.